# Item Position in RecyclerView and SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView that when the user clicks any item it will open an activity which the user must finish some tasks and if the user completes the tasks, it will be recorded in a SharePrefrences (Up to here there's no problem) then if the user returns to the recyclerView an image which I already defined in the layout will be Visible which means this step is finished already. But here comes the problem when the user after finishing the tasks returns to the recyclerView except for the selected item some of the other items also visible in the image.

**For example**, I click item one and finish all the tasks then return to the recyclerView, and except Item one, item 8, 16, and 24 also Visible the image.
Here is the necessary code to see:

In the Task activity:

```
private void trophyGiftRecycler() {

        if ((Integer)img_test1_p1.getTag()==R.drawable.alph1_a) {
            SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("prefs1", MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean letter1 = prefs1.getBoolean("letter1", true);
            if (letter1) {
                trophyShared();
            }
        }
}

private void trophyShared() {

        if ((Integer)img_test1_p1.getTag()==R.drawable.alph1_a) {
            SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("prefs1", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("letter1", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
}

In the MainAdapter

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemLetter.setImageResource(mainModelAlphabets.get(position).getItemImages());
        holder.itemTxt.setImageResource(mainModelAlphabets.get(position).getItemTxt());

        holder.itemLetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(canStart) {
                    canStart = false; // do canStart false
                    // Do what you don't want to run twice due to double tap

                    if (position==0){

                        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Alphabet2.class);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word1",R.drawable.alphabet_a1);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word2",R.drawable.alphabet_a2);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word3",R.drawable.alphabet_a3);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_in_left,R.anim.activity_slide_out_right);

                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        activity.onBackPressed();
                    }

                    if (position==1){

                        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Alphabet2.class);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word1",R.drawable.alphabet_b1);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word2",R.drawable.alphabet_b2);
                        intent.putExtra("alphabet_word3",R.drawable.alphabet_b3);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_in_left,R.anim.activity_slide_out_right);

                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        activity.onBackPressed();
                    }

        });

        setAnimation(holder.itemView,position);


        SharedPreferences prefs1 = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs1", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs2", MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean letter1 = prefs1.getBoolean("letter1", false);
        boolean letter2 = prefs2.getBoolean("letter2", false);


        if (letter1){
            if (position==0){
                holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        if (letter2){
            if (position==1){
                holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see it is supposed to visible the image in positions 1 or 2 but it visible in other positions (not all_ as well.

Comment: Add Else part also . inside `onBindViewHolder` . You have set visibility for if part but not else part .

Comment: That also will invisible the image in other views as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this snippet, add to the bottom of `onBindViewHolder`

```
boolean letter1 = prefs1.getBoolean("letter1", false);
boolean letter2 = prefs2.getBoolean("letter2", false);

if ((letter1 || letter2) && position==1) {
    holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

check out how `RecyclerView` works and what is recycling in terms of Android. in short: `View`s/list items are reused when some item scrolls outside screen then same `View` enters from another side (scrolled-out to top will be shown at the bottom as next list item). you aren't setting `View.GONE` so recycled list item still have `View.VISIBLE` for your trophy icon

edit:

simple way

```
if (position==1){
    holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(letter1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

more sophisticated

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs" + (position+1), MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean letterSet = prefs.getBoolean("letter" + (position+1), false);
holder.itemTrophy.setVisibility(letterSet ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: The else statement will invisible the image in other views as well.

Comment: `else` statement will hide `itemTrophy` for list item at particular `position`, not all, isn't this what you need? another case is what you are storing under `"letter1"` and `"letter2"` variables and when `if` statement is fulfilled

Comment: if ((letter1) && position==0){
            itemView.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            itemView.itemTrophy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

Comment: in code posted in question there is no relation between `letter1` and `position==0` - both `letter` flags are related to `position==1` (bug in logic?). when you understood how recycling works then fitting proper circumstances for `if else` won't be a problem

Comment: I have 26 boolean letter1,2,3,...,26, when the letter1 conditions meet it will let the trophy in recycler view Visible in the else statement that you said it will invisible the rest, example if you get the trophy for letter 2 after that it only let the trophy in position 1 be visible and not the rest, so in that case the letter1 is invisible as well.

Comment: In the question, I just removed the repeated parts to shorten the questions.

Comment: edited my answer, maybe now it will fit your needs. btw. do you really need separated `SharedPreferences`  for every flag? why won't keep all of them in one file?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works perfectly the one under more sophisticated.

Comment: glad I've helped :) consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful. good luck!

Comment: there is no accept of my ans, but nevermind ;) good luck again!

Comment: My reputation is less than 15 so it doesn't show my vote publicly :(

Comment: there is a check mark also for accepting answer, this you can do for shure, as "owner" of question