# Saving State of RecyclerView Checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, checkboxlist

I'm a bit new to Android development.

I was wondering how I can save state of checkboxes in a RecyclerView. I know there are existing solutions for this, but I have a list of items in another RecyclerView that uses the same set of checkboxes. When you click an item, it should show all checkboxes and check those previously checked checkboxes for that item.

I have seen posts using **SharedPreferences** to save the state but I have different checkboxes states for different item click in another RecyclerView and I do not know how to save these different states.

This is the Adapter class for the list of checkboxes named **CurrentAddonAdapter.java**:

```
public class CurrentAddonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrentAddonAdapter.ViewHolder17> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList items3,price3;
private List<AddonList> addonlist1;
private OnItemClickListener17 mOnItemClickListener17;

CurrentAddonAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items3, ArrayList price3,List addonlist1,OnItemClickListener17 onItemClickListener17){
    this.context = context;
    this.items3 = items3;
    this.price3 = price3;
    this.addonlist1 = addonlist1;
    this.mOnItemClickListener17 = onItemClickListener17;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder17 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addoncard,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder17(view,mOnItemClickListener17);
}

private SparseBooleanArray selecteditems = new SparseBooleanArray();
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CurrentAddonAdapter.ViewHolder17 holder, int position) {
    holder.item1.setText(String.valueOf(items3.get(position)));
    holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(price3.get(position)));
    final AddonList currentaddon = addonlist1.get(position);

    holder.item1.setChecked(selecteditems.get(position));
    holder.item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(holder.item1.isChecked()){
                holder.item1.setChecked(true);
                mOnItemClickListener17.onItemCheck(currentaddon);

            }
            else{
                holder.item1.setChecked(false);
                mOnItemClickListener17.onItemUncheck(currentaddon);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items3.size();

}


public class ViewHolder17 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView price1;
    CheckBox item1;
    OnItemClickListener17 onItemClickListener17;

    public ViewHolder17(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener17 onItemClickListener17) {
        super(itemView);

        item1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addoncheck);
        price1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceadd);
        this.onItemClickListener17 = onItemClickListener17;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener17.onItemClick7(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener17{
    void onItemClick7(int position);
    void onItemCheck(AddonList addonList);
    void onItemUncheck(AddonList addonList);

}
```

}

This is the code for the item click. It shows a dialog box with the list of all checkboxes with CardView elements array named **items3** and **price3**

```
  Cursor viewaddon = db.viewalladdon();
    while(viewaddon.moveToNext()){
        items3.add(viewaddon.getString(2));
        price3.add(viewaddon.getString(3));
        addonlist1.add(new AddonList(viewaddon.getString(2)));
    }
    addrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    currentAddonAdapter = new CurrentAddonAdapter(getActivity(),items3,price3,addonlist1,this);
    addrecycler.setAdapter(currentAddonAdapter);
    addrecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Please, help. I've been trying to find a solution for weeks and I still can't find one. I just really need this for school.

Comment: Hi,do you mean the check box not save state when scroll yes but please share some code so that we can help you

Comment: Hello! @ShayKin, he scrolling is not the problem. I have another list with all the items using the same checkbox list and they should have different states but when I click an item, it has the same checkbox state with the previous item. Also, I edited the post with the code. Thank you. :)

Comment: if I understood correctly you have two lists the first to check these checkboxes and the other to display what we have checked

Comment: Yes, I want to display the checked ones after but first I have a RecyclerView list with other data and when I click an item on the list, it would display a dialog box with the checkbox list and the user can check whatever he wants and when I close the dialog box and click the same item again in the RecyclerView list, it should open the dialog box again and display the same checkbox list but with items checked.  Also, when I click a different item in the RecyclerView list, the checkbox list should not be checked 'cause it is a different item. Sorry if it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you know the number of chekbox I mean are pre defined and all the same count for each item

Comment: Yes, the checkbox list count is the same for each item but the checkbox list is not predefined since you can add items to checkbox list.

Comment: I asked for the number because I've already gone through a few things like that but in my case my Chekbox List only contains 12 item and it's fix. to back it up I converted the whole list into an Integer number I considered the list as a binary number for that I save an integer

Comment: But what if the checkbox number is not predefined meaning I can add items to checkbox list? For backing up the list, how did you retrieve them?

Comment: It doesn't help you to use sqlite to save all those checkboIt doesn't help you to use the sqlite to save all those checkbox

Comment: I think you can find your solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870371/11850467

Comment: It would be really tricky to solve it this way. 
Why don't you use a very simple Item class with Item name, its price, its addonList and a boolean to keep the state of checkbox. Just use this class object list to populate your recycler view. Now every time the recycler view item is clicked it will have the correct object.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain further. Will the checkbox state change for different items? Thanks